# Proving $\int_0^{\pi/2-\phi_x} \chi^*\cos\psi\sin\psi\,d\psi = \frac\pi4(1-\sin\phi_x)$, where $\cos\chi^*=\tan \phi_x \tan \psi$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I want to prove the following result
$$
I_1(\phi_x)
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2-\phi_x}
\chi^* \cos{\psi} \sin{\psi} d\psi
= \frac{\pi}{4}[1 - \sin \phi_x ]
$$
where
$\cos \chi^* = \tan \phi_x \tan \psi$.

For $\phi_x=0$,it holds
$$I_1(0)
=\frac{\pi}{2}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
 \cos{\psi} \sin{\psi} d\psi
=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(2\psi) d\psi=
\frac{\pi}{4} [-\frac12 \cos(2\psi) ]^{\pi/2}_0 =
\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

I have done experiments in Matlab and this is true but I do not know how to proceed in the general case. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I find myself greatly disliking
the notation used.
The Greek letters and 
seemingly unnecessary
subscripts and superscripts
really bug me.

Why not enter it like this:

$\begin{array}\\
I(a)
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2-a}
b \cos{x} \sin{x} dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2-a}
 \cos^{-1}( \tan a \tan x) \cos{x} \sin{x} dx\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4}[1 - \sin a ]\\
\end{array}
$

since
$\cos b = \tan a \tan x
$
or
$b
= \cos^{-1}( \tan a \tan x)
$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}
I(\phi) &= \int_{0}^{\frac\pi2-\phi} \arccos\bigg(\tan(\phi) \tan(\psi)\bigg) \cos(\psi) \sin(\psi) \, d\psi \\[1ex]
&= \int_{0}^1 \arccos(\alpha) \frac{\alpha\cot^2(\phi)}{\left(1+\alpha^2\cot^2(\phi)\right)^2} \, d\alpha \tag{1} \\[1ex]
&= \int_{0}^1 \int_\alpha^1 \frac{\alpha\cot^2(\phi)}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2} \left(1+\alpha^2\cot^2(\phi)\right)^2} \, d\beta\,d\alpha\tag{2} \\[1ex]
&= \int_{0}^1 \int_0^\beta \frac{\alpha\cot^2(\phi)}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2} \left(1+\alpha^2\cot^2(\phi)\right)^2} \, d\alpha\,d\beta \tag{3} \\[1ex]
&= \int_{0}^1 \frac{\beta^2\cot^2(\phi)}{2(1+\beta^2\cot^2(\phi))\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} \,d\beta \\[1ex]
&= \frac{\cot^2(\phi)}2 \int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\sin^2(\gamma)}{1+\sin^2(\gamma)\cot^2(\phi)} \, d\gamma \tag{4} \\[1ex]
&= \frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \left(1 - \frac1{1+\sin^2(\gamma)\cot^2(\phi)}\right) \, d\gamma \tag{5} \\[1ex]
&= \frac\pi4 - \frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \frac1{1+\sin^2(\gamma)\cot^2(\phi)} \, d\gamma \\[1ex]
&= \frac\pi4 - \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac1{1+\delta^2\csc^2(\phi)} \, d\delta \tag{6} \\[1ex]
&= \frac\pi4 - \frac12 \sin(\phi) \int_0^{\frac\pi2} d\epsilon \tag{7} \\[1ex]
&= \boxed{\frac\pi4 (1-\sin(\phi))}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $\alpha=\tan(\phi) \tan(\psi)$
- $(2)$ : [integral definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Expression_as_definite_integrals) of $\arccos$
- $(3)$ : reverse order of integration
- $(4)$ : substitute $\beta=\sin(\gamma)$
- $(5)$ : partial fractions (optional)
- $(6)$ : substitute $\delta=\tan(\gamma)$
- $(7)$ : substitute $\delta=\sin(\phi)\tan(\epsilon)$